# Flutter: many items in Wrap in a ScrollView. How to build only those that are visible to the user, like ListView.builder(), for performance reasons?

Tags: flutter

I have the following:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Wrap(
    children: itemsOfVaryingWidth
  ),
);
```

Is something like this possible, and how?

```
return ScrollingWrap.builder(
  itemCount: itemsOfVaryingWidth.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => itemsOfVaryingWidth[index],
);
```

Thanks a ton!

Comment: If manyItem means >7 or >15. I may prefer using search functionality.